# Reading file byte by byte without exceeding memory limit

Tags: python, file, byte

I would like to read a very big file(100GB) in Python. If I use just

```
with open("test.test", 'rb') as f:
     data = f.read()
```

It will produce a `MemoryError`. I came up with the idea of reading that file byte by byte.  I tried

```
with open("test.txt", 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(1)
```

And everything was perfect; only one byte was read. The problem comes with reading the next bytes. If I replace argument `1` with `2` the output of that will be 2 bytes, not seconds byte. I could use the split function, but in that specific function, I need to not exceed the memory limit. Is there any way to read file byte by byte? Or is there any solution?

Comment: If you call `read(1)` again, you will get the next byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [seek](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek). Just increment the offset as you want.